# How to Write Proxy Methods?

Tags: c#, proxy-classes

First I don't know the term of "Proxy Methods" are true way to describe what I need is but let me tell what I really want to know actually :

Suppose I have a class, named Proxy Class containing proxy methods

```
class ProxyMethods
{
   public void CallHelloWorld();
}
```

actually this is a mirror, actual codes are storing in a web server. So how would this method call the real method that is locating in Web Server without using webservices ?

This way would secure my own code, if a refactoring software refactors the dll located in client's computer, then only thing it would show is that basic method signatures and some connection data which is used to connect the real classes located in Web Server.

So how would I accomplish it ?

Maybe Remoting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are trying to avoid web services.  Performance concerns?  Regardless, WCF is the way to go these days.  Remoting is nearly totally obsolete.  With WCF, it is a config change to go from traditional SOAP over HTTP web service transport to a binary, encrypted transport if you wish.  There are so many options to tune the traffic, security, etc. to your needs.

Comment: +1 The great thing is that WCF can make the choice of protocol and transport used almost redundant, as you can change these things easily .